# How do I calculate the Intensity of this electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider this situation:
A dipole with amplitude $p_0$ has a dipole moment of:
$$\textbf{p}(t) = p_0 \textbf{z} e^{-i\omega t}$$
and emits a field:
$$\textbf{E}(t) = \frac{\omega^2}{4\pi c^2 r} e^{i(\frac{\omega r}{c} - \omega t)} p_0 (\textbf{n} \times \textbf {z}) \times \textbf{n}$$
which can be assumed to be a planar wave with direction of spreading $\textbf{n}$ for large distances.
Now when I try to calculate the Intensity using $I = c \epsilon_0 \textbf{E}_r(t)^2$ where $\textbf{E}_r(t)$ is the real component I get $0$. It comes up because:
$$(\textbf{n} \times \textbf {z}) \times \textbf{n} = (\textbf{n} \cdot \textbf {n}) \textbf{z} - (\textbf{n} \cdot \textbf {z}) \textbf{n}$$
Squaring this to get $I$ results in
$$z^2n^4 - 2z^2n^4 + z^2n^4 = 0$$
I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: *tell me what I'm doing wrong here* Check-my-work questions are off-topic here. (But your squaring is wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice
$$(\vec{n}  \times \vec{z}) \bot \vec{n}$$

Therefore
$$|(\vec{n}  \times \vec{z})  \times \vec{n}|^2 $$
$$=|(\vec{n}  \times \vec{z})|^2|\vec{n}|^2$$
$$=(n^2z^2\sin^2(\theta))n^2$$
$$=n^4z^2sin^2(\theta)$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{z}$ and $\vec{n}$, which can be expressed as:

$$\sin^2(\theta)=1-\cos^2(\theta)$$
$$=1-(\frac{\vec{n}\cdot\vec{z}}{|\vec{n}||\vec{z}|})^2$$
$$=\frac{n^2z^2 - (\vec{n}\cdot\vec{z})^2}{n^2z^2}$$ Plug back into original yields

$$|(\vec{n}  \times \vec{z})  \times \vec{n}|^2 $$
$$=n^2(n^2z^2-(\vec{n}\cdot\vec{z})^2)$$

Which intuitively makes sense since based on the vectors you've defined there is a $E(t)  \propto n^2$ and $E(t)  \propto z$, so as expected $I  \propto n^4$ and $I  \propto z^2$

Comment: $\mathbf n$ and $\mathbf z$ are unit vectors.

Comment: Well in that case just plug in the fact that the magnitude each vector is 1 in the general expression above.